# Maven Create multi-module with same dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to create a multi-module project with the same dependencies.

For exemple I have :

```
Module A (parent)
    | Module B
    | Module C
```

Module B and C use the exact same dependencies and contains only 1 class each. I want each module to build their own JAR. The thing is, I don't want to build fat jar (Because I'll have a lot of module like this in the future)

Is there a way for the module B and C to use the same dependency ? I tried with dependencyManagement but it's not quite what I want because both jars contains the dependencies and i don't want that.

Is there a way to achieve this ? Maybe by having a module D which contain only the dependencies and each jar will use the "D.jar" ? But how to link Modules B and C to use D dependencies ?

```
Module A (parent)
   | Module D
       | Module B
       | Module C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a separate `pom.xml` as an artifact on its own.

This pom will have your dependencies **x** and **y**. Then you give your modules the dependency to this pom (via its group, artifact, and version).

Comment: It's kind of what i have achieve with dependencyManagement, I define the dependencies in the Parent and I reference these dependencies in the sub modules. But the submodule's JAR will be a fat Jar with all these dependencies in it.

Comment: Whether you get a so called _fat jar_ or not is independent of how you define the dependencies. It depends on how you build your artifact (with dependencies or not).

Comment: I know, the point is i have 2 JAR with 2 differents class but the with same dependencies inside each JAR. i'd like to remove the duplication of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If a sub-module can work with out dependencies of parent module then it can be created as an independent module. Even with the way you propose, module A dependencies will be passed to B and C via D and that is how dependency management in POM works.

Comment: Yes, the thing is, i don't want the dependencies in the Jar but instead a Jar containing only the dependency (module D) and B and C without it but uses D

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

Module A will manage the dependencies version (dependencyManagement)
B and C will define the needed dependencies

Module D will be a differents project containing utils, common and all the dependency in an uber Jar. It will be on a home Maven repo.

```
Module A (parent)
       | Module B
       | Module C
Module D
       | Utils
       | common
```